# How would you translate "Dashboard" from a web application point of view?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

I'm developing a few web applications at the moment, and they have a global database of translations behind them, so that they can be used well across various languages

My Spanish is still fairly beginner, and I'm wondering what the best way would be to translate the word 'Dashboard'.

It's used in a lot of places, i.e. "Users Dashboard", "Jobs Dashboard" etc etc, all of which are sort of a 'home page' for that section of the site. They provide an overview of the section, and have small sections of information about the different sections.

I've translated it to **salpicadero**, but as far as I know that is fairly definitively "the dashboard of a car/plane etc, instrument panel". This makes sense but doesn't really fit with the context of the application

Does anyone have any alternative suggestions I could use? Any advice or feedback would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 17):

I would use something like:

- **`Panel`** / **`Panel de control`**  which is translated as something like "screen" or "panel".
- **`Tablero`** which is translated as something like "board".

Note also that even **`Dashboard`** itself can be used, since people are getting more and more used to English names even in Spanish interfaces (for example, "log in" is quite commonly used).

Comment: +1 for panel de control. Nice one.

Comment: Since a Dashboard is typically passive (you see reports, but don't change stuff), I would at least consider pluralizing "control", to make it clear that it is a board full of controlssss (widgets), not a board for controlling anything: Panel de controles / Tablero de controles (This doesn't exclude the posibility of having switches or levers there, but it does point a bit more in the direction of "many checks/widgets" than "with this I control the airplane"

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by @fedorqui, as a native Spanish speaker, **dashboard** is well understood in software development. The full range of options would be:

- **Panel de control** which is translated as something like "screen" or "panel".
- **Dashboard** (although I like to use spanish words)
- **Consola** is more suited to something like Bash in Linux, or the device that controls the information (but more in a physical aspect). "The machine that controls the PET SCAN is a **consola**"

**Tablero** is more related to games and has nothing to do with the meaning of dashboard in this context.

But **salpicadero** is completely incorrect, since it's used for "the dashboard of a car/plane etc, instrument panel", but not the instruments themselves, it's the part that contains them. You normally place the GPS on the **salpicadero.**

**Edit:**
Thanks @Lambie for showing **tablero** is, indeed, accepted by DLE RAE https://www.rae.es/drae2001/tablero

Comment: tablero is right: https://tudashboard.com/tableros-de-negocio/

Comment: @Lambie Although is accepted by DLE RAE, https://www.rae.es/drae2001/tablero (dictionary entry 14 and 15), as a native speaker, it just doesn't sound right. Maybe that company is promoting the word. I will edit my answer thoug

Answer (score 5):

I think that for web environment, **`panel de información`** suits better according to this definition:

> A customizable landing page for a business application or workspace
>   that uses Web Parts to display selected information. It can provide a
>   comprehensive look at the information inside the application or
>   workspace by consolidating lists, libraries, text, images and other
>   data into a dynamic, customizable information portal.

As a software developer, I have used this term when translating into Spanish.

source: http://www.interglot.es/diccionario/en/es/traducir/dashboard

Answer (score 2):

There's no straightforward translation.

FWIW, the Spanish translation of Wordpress uses **"Escritorio"**.

I'd prefer slightly **"Panel"** (as suggested in other answers), perhaps better **"Panel principal"**.

Answer (score 1):

The translation should be **Tablero de comandos** but nobody uses this term in the real life. I prefer to use **Consola**

Answer (score 1):

"Dashboard" alone could be translated as "Inicio" in a mobile application context. For "Users dashboard" or "Jobs dashboard" I think the best translation is to delete the word. Spanish users will understand "Usuarios" or "Empleos" section as the main one. Maybe "Inicio usuarios" or "Inicio empleos", but is gramatically wrong and may sound weird. LinkedIn app has "Empleos" section in its sliding menu.

Im not into web development but I think it will be very similar to mobile development

Answer (score 1):

You can use probably the most common nomenclature Pantalla Principal (main screen), Pantalla de Inicio (initial screen). Or Consola (console or screen), Consola de Inicio (start screen) or Consola de Resumen (summary screen) all sound better.

Salpicadero definitely not. Escritorio is used for desktop, not dashboard. Windows uses Panel de Control (control panel) which is geared toward configuration control as opposed to the main status and operational page.

Answer (score 0):

In some applications it would be **Cuadro de mandos**.

You can also use **Resumen**, **Resumen general** or **Resumen genérico**.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already mentioned the most common translation, “panel”, but I just wanted to add another suggestion to the mix —

**Cuadro de mando** — I use this in Weblate (a web app for l10n) to connote that it’s a hub to manage the translation projects you actively and presently work on.