# ¿Cuál sería una buena traducción para "Consumer Disclosure" y "Dashboard"?

Tags: traducción, español-neutral, informática

Estoy traduciendo un sitio web al español y hay un link que dice "Consumer Disclosure". Si lo fuera a traducir al español sería:

> Divulgación de los consumidores

Pero en mi opinión suena muy rara esa expresión.

Lo mismo para la palabra "Dashboard", de la cual una traducción correcta sería:

> Tablero

Pero en el contexto del sitio no tiene mucho sentido, lo que hace ese link cuando le da click es llevarlo a la página principal. Así que me gustaría saber de alguna traducción más adecuada para estas palabras.

Nótese que el enlace de consumer disclosures lleva al usuario a [esta 
página](https://web.connectnetwork.com/consumer-disclosures/).

Comment: Existen muchas alternativas para llamar el vínculo que lleva a la página principal, pero ¿a dónde te lleva el vínculo de _Consumer Disclosure_? si das un poco más de contexto, tendrás mejores respuestas.

Comment: @DGaleano ya actualicé la pregunta.

Comment: Nótese que la consulta sobre _dashboard_ ya se hizo en [How would you translate “Dashboard” from a web application point of view?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13445/1674). De hecho, sería bueno que preguntaras una sola cosa en cada pregunta. Piensa que es gratis preguntar, no cobramos por hacerlo más de una vez :) Gracias y bienvenido a [spanish.se]

Comment: "Consumer Disclosure" translates perfectly to "Información al consumidor"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El vínculo 'Dashboard' que lleva a la página principal del sitio lo puedes llamar

- Inicio
- Menú principal
- Le puedes poner el nombre del sitio lo que intuitivamente se sabe que es el inicio de la navegación.
- No lo recomiendo pero "Home" se entiende y se ve frecuentemente.
- "Tablero de control" es la traducción más usual de *Dashboard* pero tampoco lo recomiendo.

En lo que se refiere a "Consumer disclosure" imagino que es alguna clase de 'Disclaimer' que en [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17583/traducci%C3%B3n-de-disclaimer) el foro está de acuerdo en que la mejor traducción es **Aviso**

EDICIÓN:

Luego de que modificaste la pregunta y visité el enlace creo que eso lo puedes llamar **"Información al consumidor"** o **"Quejas y reclamos"**. Por ejemplo la empresa de servicios públicos de mi ciudad lo llama "[Peticiones, quejas y reclamos](http://www.epm.com.co/site/clientes_usuarios/Clientesyusuarios/Peticiones,quejasyreclamos.aspx)"

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias por sus sugerencias. Iré por "Peticiones, quejas y reclamos".

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra Dependiendo del país, *reclamaciones* es otra alternativa a *reclamos*. En España, por ejemplo, *quejas y reclamaciones* es más común que *quejas y reclamos*.

Comment: En informática suele usarse el término "Panel de control"

Comment: Quizás _Quejas y *sugerencias*_ ?